Keyboard accessibility not working in Angular cdk overlay menu
Keyboard accessibility not working in Angular cdk overlay menu
Refs - https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/examples
I need to open menu on click a link or button and focus to 1st menu item and on key down or up focus should move to next or previous menu item. e.g. it's working in this example https://material.angular.io/cdk/menu/examples but here on click menu item, menu closed but need to keep menu open on click any menu item. that's why I am using cdk overlay.
Related question - Menu closed on click any menu item but requirement is, if clicked on item menu should open


import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {OverlayModule} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

/**
 * @title Overlay basic example
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-overlay-basic-example',
  templateUrl: './cdk-overlay-basic-example.html',
  styleUrl: './cdk-overlay-basic-example.css',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [OverlayModule],
})
export class CdkOverlayBasicExample {
  isOpen = false;
}
.example-list {
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
}

.example-list > li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #8b8b8b;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.example-list > li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}
<!-- This button triggers the overlay and is it's origin -->
<button (click)="isOpen = !isOpen" type="button" cdkOverlayOrigin #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
  {{isOpen ? "Close" : "Open"}}
</button>

<!-- This template displays the overlay content and is connected to the button -->
<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen"
>
  <ul class="example-list" cdkMenu cdkTrapFocus [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true">
    <li cdkMenuItem>Item 1</li>
    <li #refresh cdkMenuItem>Refresh</li>
    <li cdkMenuItem>Item 3</li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>




Use a cdkMenu like the first example in the docs instead of use simple ul. NOTE: You can use also focusTrap in order to traps Tab key focus within an element. NOTE2: Really a cdkMenu is harded based in the package cdk/a11 and use internally listKey manager

@Eliseo Thanks for suggestion, cdkTrapFocus is working but also I need to focus particular menu item programmatically. How we can do this? I tried listKey manager and focus monitor but these are not working. any solution, please share

Tried CdkMenuItem focus method but it's not working e.g. @ViewChild('refresh') refItem: CdkMenuItem | undefined;   and this.refItem?.focus()

@Eliseo Required cdkTrapFocus [cdkTrapFocusAutoCapture]="true" both to capture keyboard accessibility but I am still looking to focus particular menu item programmatically, If any solution please share
